# Why does java complain about raw types in my variable declaration?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public class Table<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {

/*
* The purpose of entry is to glue together a key and a value
*
* The class that we use for Key has to implement comparable
* */
private class Entry<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> implements Comparable<Entry>
{
    Key key;
    Value value;

    public Entry(Key k, Value v)
    {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    public int compareTo(Entry<Key,Value> entry)
    {
        return key.compareTo(entry.key);
    }
}

private BST<Table.Entry<Key, Value>> tree = new BST<Table.Entry<Key, Value>>();

//must supply public methods for the three operations

public Value lookUp(Key key)
{
    Entry<Key, Value> e = new Entry<Key, Value>(key, null);

    return tree.search(e).value;
}

public boolean insert(Key k, Value v)
{
    return tree.insert(new Entry<Key, Value>(k, v));
}

public boolean delete(Key k)
{
    //we haven't written a delete method for bst yet.
    return tree.delete(new Entry(k, null));
}
}
```

The above is a class declaration for a table abstract data type that my professor was going over in class. I've been trying to figure out why does Java give me the following error message

> Type arguments given on raw type

When I declare my variable here

```
private BST<Table.Entry<Key, Value>> tree = new BST<Table.Entry<Key, Value>>();
```

What are raw types in java? We've discussed writing generic classes. Is it related to that?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read this if you followed the convention of giving type parameters 1-character names (`K`, `V`).  Without that it's difficult to spot where you're referencing a real class and where you're using a parameter.

Comment: You haven't shown us what actually matters: the definition of the class `BST`.

Comment: @MarkPeters: Great! Bring back single-character identifiers - just what we need to improve code readability.

Comment: @AdrianPronk: There is no "bring back."  Whether you agree with it or not, it's already the extremely well established [Java convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).  Following conventions enhances readability in this case over using a descriptive name (which appears to suggest that it's not a type parameter but rather a class name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table class requires generic parameters, but you are referencing it as a raw type here:

> private BST<**Table**.Entry> tree = new BST<**Table**.Entry>();

You need to supply generic parameters for it, as so:

```
private BST<Table<Key, Value>.Entry<Key, Value>> tree = 
    new BST<Table<Key, Value>.Entry<Key, Value>>();
```

And as others have pointed out, its standard to define generic parameters as one letter characters, so `K` instead of `Key`, and `V` instead of `Value`. It makes it ***substantially*** easier to read and understand your code, and helps avoid confusion with real type names.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But I still don't really understand why you have to do it that way? Why do I specifically have to call Table.Entry and not just use Entry? Shouldn't anything that is in Entry be available to table since Entry is an inner class of Table?

Comment: @j.jerrod.taylor - Absolutely. You can actually remove the `Table` portion entirely, all its doing is providing scope thats not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry` is a raw type, while `Entry<Key, Value>` is not. o, in your code, the snippet :

```
public boolean delete(Key k)
{
    //we haven't written a delete method for bst yet.
    return tree.delete(new Entry(k, null));
}
```

is including a raw type.

Comment: You know, you can flag the question as duplicated instead of giving a very simple explanation contrasted by the answer in the possible duplicated link.